# Bcrypt.compare not comparing the passwords

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I have a bcrypt.compare function, but it couldn't compare the passwords rather any password entered was able to return status ok. See the code below and help me out.Thanks

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, users.password).then(
    (valid) => { 
        if (!valid) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: new Error('Incorrect password!')
            });
        }
        const token = jwt.sign(
            { userId: users._id },
            'RANDOM_TOKEN_SECRET',
            { expiresIn: '24h' }
        );
        res.status(200).json({
            userId: users._id,
            token: 'token'
        });
    }
).catch(
    (error) => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: error
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Could you provide an example `req.body.password` and `users.password` value?

Comment: what is `req.body.password` and `users.password`? plaintext, hash?

Comment: one more question is why do you use `users` in the arguments and send him back `user` in `user._id`

Comment: Example of the req.body.password value is Jennifer while the users.password is the hashed password value. Even when I commented out the user in user.id part  I still got the error. Please more solution is needed

Answer (score 0):

I once had some like this before. How long is your password column or table ? Bcrypt hashes the password with an string greater than 60 chars. Is it your column on that range ?

Comment: I don't get your answer, please make me be on the same page

Comment: yes I am assuming you have a users table in your db. one of its column is the users, password. how many characters long is it?

Comment: The least character for email is 7 while the hashed password is 60 in character. Is there any resolution to this please

Comment: but what if the problem is not in the compaere method, but in encrypter.
https://github.com/EnetoJara/rest-resume-api/blob/master/src/utils/password.ts